# Gitlab-CI difference between multiline script and multiple scripts

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci, kubernetes-helm, continuous-deployment

Fairly new to GitLab-CI, I'm trying to deploy via Helm on a Kubernetes cluster.
I have this:

```
image: docker:stable

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  image:
    name: alpine/helm:3.4.1
  script:
    - echo "Deploying to production"
    - helm list --all-namespaces
```

And it fails with:

```
Error: unknown command "sh" for "helm"
```

And the `echo` is not echoed, however, If I were to remove the `echo` line, the `helm` cmd would execute successfully.

I guess I'm asking how to make multiline scripts run? How do the gitlab-runner executes the series of commands provided in the `script:` array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each entry in the `script` array runs in an `sh` shell.

```
sh -x 'echo "Deploying to production"'
```

The `alpine/helm` image you are using contains an entrypoint of `helm`
Which means the `sh` command gitlab is trying to run is being appended to the entrypoint as an argument (e.g. `helm sh -x 'echo "Deploying to production"'`)

[Override the entrypoint](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/2692)

```
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  image:
    name: alpine/helm:3.4.1
  entrypoint: [""]
  script:
    - echo "Deploying to production"
```